# How to exclude realm native files from library

Tags: android, realm

**Problem:** How to remove Realm .so files in library (aar) published using jitpack (leave only realm java files)

We currently moved part of our functionality to sdk, we are creating. Because Realm adds .so libs for each architecture, our sdk becomes too large. 
I wanted to leave our RealmObjects in sdk, but remove native files (we actually use realm in our app, not in sdk).

**Clarification:**

- We share our model for realm and retrofit, so this is why it should stay in sdk
- Realm doesn't support inheritance for not realm-object so model can't be extended in app.

So my solution was to add packeging options:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'lib/mips/librealm-jni.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/librealm-jni.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86/librealm-jni.so'
    exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/librealm-jni.so'
}
```

And it works well, but only when app using sdk adds it in build.grade. Using this in build.gradle for sdk doesn't work.

**Questions**

1. How can this be achived?
2. What are alternatives to solve this problem (having model in sdk, but having database for that model in app using sdk)?

Comment: One option could be to ignore the Realm plugin and just add the dependencies manually using the `provided` scope instead of `compile`. It requires a bit of tinkering though as you would also manually need to add the transformer: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/gradle-plugin/src/main/groovy/io/realm/gradle/Realm.groovy#L57